# "Object Variable or With Block Variable not Set"

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to loop through the workbook, take some value and store in a different sheet. Below is my code. Keepp getting VBA Object Variable or With Block Variable not Set Error.

Can someone help me spot where is wrong?

```
Sub analysis()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

For i = 4 To 197
    ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    ws.Cells(1, 9) = ìstandardevî
    ws.Cells(2, 9) = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range("D3:D34"))
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(2, 1) = ws.Cells(2, 1)
    Sheets(4).Cells(2, 2) = ws.Cells(3, 8)
    Sheets(4).Cells(2, 3) = ws.Cells(2, 9)
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

The first line inside the For/Next loop is this:

```
ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i)
```

Change it to this:

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i)
```

Comment: In VBA, any variable that is not a primitive type (number, string, date, etc.) must be "SET", not just assigned to.  I always forget this whenever I go back to VBA after some extended time away.

Comment: You can also do "inline" sets like this "Dim mySheet as Worksheet: Set mySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)".  It won't help for your current loop situation, but can be handy.

Comment: @CarlFriedRiceGauss Only object variables must be set and only when the New keyword is not used when the variable is dim'd. Your assertion is overly broad.

Comment: @CarlFriedRiceGauss that's technically not "inline" as the colon is parsed as a new line. I would recommend against it just for general readability sake, too :)

Comment: @ExcelHero I thought everything that wasn't primitive was an object in VBA.  Is this not the case?